# Text exceeding width in web view

Tags: android

I am developing a simple application on web view. When loading the text in  web view the text is exceeding the page in its width, can anyone help me to display the text in next line instead of going out of the page? The image is as shown below!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKzJ3.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="510dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txttimemlcq"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="@string/hhjh" 
    android:textColor="#FF0000"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webviewmultiple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtquiztype" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webviewmultiple"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox0"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox1"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox2"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnbackmul"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/bac" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnnextmul"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/nextmul" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsubmitmul"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/submitmul" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtquiztype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/multi"
    android:textColor="#00FFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtmultiquesno"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtquiztype"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FF9933"/>
```

Comment: Could you post some of your xml or code or both pls?

Comment: share your css of the web page you are displaying

Comment: Check out this link might be this could help you 
    https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre>` tag instead of `<p>` in your HTML and give `<pre>` style as

```
pre{white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-all;}
```